# Register a site-setting-like to appear under custom Wagtail sidebar menu

Tags: django-admin, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have created a custom menu section for my Wagtail models (Major and Minor) using `wagtail_hooks`. They appear fine under a custom ModelAdminGroup:

```
── Wagtail
    ├── Pages
    ├── Images
    ├── Documents
    ├── Snippets
    ├── Shops
    │   ├── Major
    │   └── Minor
    │   └── ...
    ├── .
    ├── .
    ├── .
    └── Settings
```

Now, I have some details around shops that needs to be store more like a setting field and not in a Page model. The common way of doing this is to register this new feature (`Shop Contacts`) in settings by using the `register_setting` decorator. This will result in `Shop Contacts` appearing under `Settings`.

However, what I want to achieve is to move it under `Shops` so it looks something like this:

```
── Wagtail
    ├── Pages
    ├── Images
    ├── Documents
    ├── Snippets
    ├── Shops
    │   ├── Major
    │   └── Minor
    │   └── ...
    │   └── Shop Contacts
    ├── .
    ├── .
    ├── .
    └── Settings
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is pretty similar to the LibraryGroup example in https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html#a-more-complicated-example